# How to test a gem with RSpec that extends ActiveRecord models?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails

I am moving some code we use into a gem.  The code allows you to create breadcrumbs on ActiveRecord models like so:

```
Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_breadcrumbs
end
```

My question is - how do I use Rspec in my gem to mock/stub these abstract AR objects?  So essentially, I need to create 'fake' active record objets, add my `has_breadcrumbs` to them, then use these mocked records in my specs.

In my spec_helper.rb I'm including:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rails/all'
require 'rspec/rails'
```

I need to test that the gem is working correctly by ensuring my `has_breadcrumbs` is responding correctly and allowing me to apply settings against AR models.  However, I'm finding this tricky since I don't have a DB instead I need to mock these objects somehow.

Some code examples would be great to give me an idea on what's the best practice for this sort of thing.

Comment: since your gem is using AR it would be awful to not include the AR dependency in your specs. Just create a Model class in your specs and try to test against this model. Here is an example for a Sequel plugin: https://github.com/sdepold/sequel-bit_fields/blob/master/spec/sequel/plugins/bit_fields_spec.rb. But this should easily adaptable for AR.

Comment: If you don't want to use the database, you can use nulldb https://github.com/nulldb/nulldb

Comment: what does has_breadcrumbs do that you'll be testing?

Comment: If you're testing your gem properly, you don't need ActiveRecord and if you had some interaction with it within your test you should be stubbing that out. ActiveRecord is tested elsewhere.